# Python - IndexError: list index out of range NOT being thrown when it should be

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

Not sure if this is BECAUSE of Jupyter Notebook or just that Python HANDLES the exception, but I was solving a problem involving algorithms with a friend

While whiteboarding the code, I used Python!

```
exampleList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in range(0, len(exampleList)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(exampleList)):
        print(exampleList[i], exampleList[j])
```

Basically, the debate was that.. This code (a similar one, I have used a simple example to illustrate) involving two `for` loops MUST throw an error! Because, index `i` reached `len(exampleList) - 1`, and index `j` technically will become `len(exampleList)` and at that point, `print(exampleList[i], exampleList[j])` cannot work! It looks like while running the code, it does print out perfectly, and I think HANDLES the `IndexError: list index out of range` exception!

My question is.. Is this supposed to be intended behaviour in Python? Because the person I was debating with ended up telling me that 'The people conducting your interview notice these things! You must be able to explain every line.'

I would like to understand how this part is handled so I can explain why this does not throw an error!

Comment: As a way of testing your theory, try to put a `print(i,j)` in your loop and see if `j` ever equals 5.

Comment: i test your code by copy-past locale and it's work fine

Comment: Or even `print(list(range(i + 1, len(exampleList))))` inside the loop. You will see what happens.

Comment: @BearBrown, yes, that's the point. He's saying that the code isn't crashing, but he thinks that it should crash.

Comment: @Kevin thank you but why if `i` and `j` always inside the list index range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range` function is inclusive of lower bound, but *exclusive* of upper bound.

Your example list has 5 elements. This means that the first loop is running `range(0,5)`, making the max `i=4`. Which makes the second loop have a max value of `range(5,5)`, which is an empty list. Iterating over an empty list causes 0 iterations.

```
>>> exampleList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> len(exampleList)
5
>>> range(0, 5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(5,5)
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood how [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) works.

`Range()` stops counting at the first value less than the given stop value, which in your case will be equivalent to `len(exampleList)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, `j` never equals `len(exampleList)`. You say `j in range(i + 1, len(exampleList))`, which means `j` will also always be less than `len(exampleList)`. And, if `i+1 >= len(exampleList)`, the range will be empty because `range(m, n)` where `m >= n` is always empty.

So the error is never even thrown because erroneous code is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, we have len(array) = **5**.

The range function on the first loop will return 5 values iteratively - **[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]**. That means that the issue number should be the last, **4**, right?

But actually, when you attempt to enter the second loop, ***range(4 + 1, 5)*** will essentially return a blank list of numbers, therefore it won't run the contents of the loop at all.
Hence, no error.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how exampleList[i] is never e?  Once your first for loop hits len(exampleList) - 1, the inner loop fails because it is checking if i + 1 is less than the length of exampleList (which it isn't), therefore the print statement is never reached causing the exception to not be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is no mistake on Python's part. The exception only becomes a worry when trying to access `exampleList[5]`, which is never requested by the loop. It is important to remember that `range()` is exclusive of the upper limit, but inclusive of the lower.

Below I added some comments to the right to explain

```
exampleList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in range(0, len(exampleList)): # includes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(exampleList)): # includes all numbers in range[0,4] greater than i
        print(exampleList[i], exampleList[j]) # will never exceed 4
```

Comment: I would also replace your `<-----` with `#` which would be valid Python syntax. This would allow people to copy-paste your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the last iteration of the outermost loop, j will start equal to len(example). Therefore, the j-loop is not even executed in this iteration. Because the range is between len(example) and len(example) - 1.